# If you make the bracha of shehacol over a food that is haetz do you need to make another bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

If someone makes the bracha of shehacol over a food that is haetz does he need to make another bracha?

Comment: [Welcome to MY Micol](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501), great to have you here and hope to see you around learning with us.

Answer (score 5):

The Mishna in Berachos ([6:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=107)) discusses this case.

> בירך על פירות האילן בורא פרי האדמה יצא ועל פירות הארץ בורא פרי העץ לא
>   יצא על כולם אם אמר שהכל נהיה יצא
>
> IF ONE SAYS OVER FRUIT OF THE TREE THE BENEDICTION, ‘WHO CREATEST THE
>   FRUIT OF THE GROUND, HE HAS PERFORMED HIS OBLIGATION. BUT IF HE SAID
>   OVER PRODUCE OF THE GROUND, ‘WHO CREATEST THE FRUIT OF THE TREE’, HE
>   HAS NOT PERFORMED HIS OBLIGATION. IF HE SAYS ‘BY WHOSE WORD ALL THINGS
>   EXIST OVER ANY OF THEM, HE HAS PERFORMED HIS OBLIGATION. ([Soncino
>   translation; capitals in original](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

This law is codified by [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) in [Hilchos Berachos 8:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=82441&rid=1060)

> בירך על פירות האילן בורא פרי האדמה יצא ועל פירות האדמה בורא פרי העץ לא
>   יצא ועל כולם אם בירך שהכל יצא ואפי' על הפת ועל היין
>
> A person who recited the blessing borey pri ha'adamah over fruits that
>   grow on trees fulfills his obligation. Conversely, one who recited the
>   blessing borey pri ha'etz over fruits that grow from the ground does
>   not fulfill his obligation. One who recites the blessing shehakol over
>   any food fulfills his obligation. [This applies even in regard] to
>   bread and wine. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927676/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-Eight.htm))

This law is reiterated by the [Tur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher) in [O.C. 206](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x891)

> בירך על פירות האילן בורא פרי האדמה יצא ואם בירך על פרי האדמה בורא פרי
>   העץ לא יצא הילכך אם אדם מסופק בפרי אם הוא פרי עץ או פרי האדמה מברך 
>   בורא פרי האדמה ועל הכל אם אמר שהכל נהיה בדברו יצא
>
> If one made the blessing of "borei peri ha'adama" on fruit of the
>   tree, he has discharged his obligation. But if he made the blessing of
>   "borei peri ha'etz" on fruit of the ground, he has not discharged his
>   obligation. Therefore, if a man is unsure if a fruit is a fruit of the
>   tree or a fruit of the ground he should make the blessing of "borei
>   peri ha'adama". On everything if he said "shehakol" he has discharged
>   his obligation.

It is again reiterated by the [Shulchan Aruch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) in [O.C. 206](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1030)

> בירך על פירות האילן בורא פרי האדמה יצא אבל אם בירך על פרי האדמה בורא
>   פרי העץ לא יצא הלכך אם הוא מסופק בפרי אם הוא פרי עץ או פרי האדמה מברך
>   בורא פרי האדמה ועל הכל אם אמר שהכל יצא ואפילו על פת ויין
>
> If one made the blessing of "borei peri ha'adama" on fruit of the
>   tree, he has discharged his obligation. But if he made the blessing of
>   "borei peri ha'etz" on fruit of the ground, he has not discharged his
>   obligation. Therefore, if one is unsure if a fruit is a fruit of the
>   tree or a fruit of the ground he should make the blessing of "borei
>   peri ha'adama". On everything if he said "shehakol" he has discharged
>   his obligation, even on bread or wine.

This law is also codified by the [Aruch Hashulchan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein) in [O.C. 206:2-3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=383), but he adds the caveat that when you make the non-primary beracha on a fruit it only covers the fruits in front of you. If more fruit is brought out, the correct beracha must then be made.

> מיהו לכתחלה אסור לברך על דבר שוודאי ברכתו העץ בפה"א ואפילו מונח לפניו
>   שני דברים שרוצה לאכלן אחת ברכתו העץ ואחת האדמה כמו צנון וזית לא יברך
>   על הצנון האדמה ויכוין לפטור את הזית אלא מברך מקודם על הזית העץ ואח"כ
>   מברך על הצנון והאדמה דברכת העץ קודם לברכת האדמה ואפילו אם הקדים לברך
>   על הצנון האדמה אם לא כיון מפורש לפטור את הזית מברך אח"כ העץ על הזית
>   ואין זה מרבה בברכות כיון שאין זה עיקר ברכתו מיהו בדיעבד אם בירך על
>   הצנון האדמה וכיון לפטור את הזית יצא ואסור לו לברך אח"כ על הזית העץ
>   דהוי ברכה לבטלה וכבר נתבאר דעל כולם אם אמר שהכל יצא אפילו על פת ויין
>   וכ"ש שארי דברים וכן כשיש פרי העץ שמברכין האדמה כגון בוסר בענבים או
>   קפריסין בצלף וכיוצא בהם כפי הדינים שנתבארו בסי' ר"ב אם בירך עליהם העץ
>   יצא דסוף סוף פרי העץ הם [מג"א סק"א] וכן בפרי האדמה לעניין שהכל כהאי
>   גוונא]
>
> יראה לי דאע"ג דקיי"ל אם בירך על העץ האדמה דיצא זהו לעניין הפירות
>   המונחים לפניו ולא להפירות שאינם לפניו כלומר דהנה האוכל תפוחים ובירך
>   העץ והביאו לפניו עוד תפוחים יצא בברכתו הראשונה כמו שיתבאר וזהו כשבירך
>   העץ אבל כשבירך האדמה ולא כיון מפורש לפטור התפוחים שיביאו אח"כ מברך על
>   התפוחים שאח"כ העץ שהרי לכתחלה אין לברך על העץ האדמה אלא שבדיעבד יצא
>   ואין לנו אלא על מה שלפניו ולא על מה שיביאו אח"כ וכ"ש כשבירך על הצנון
>   והיתה כוונתו לפטור את הזית והביאו אח"כ זיתים אחרים דמברך עליהם העץ
>   [והט"ז סק"ב רוצה לומר דגם בכה"ג פוטר ותמה על הש"ע ע"ש ודבריו תמוהים
>   וכבר תמה עליו השאגת אריה סי' כ"ז ומהר"י והרשב"א אין ראיה כלל ע"ש וכן
>   נלע"ד בכל הברכות שבדיעבד יוצאין בהן כמו שהכל אין זה אלא על מה שלפניו
>   ודו"ק]

Answer (score 2):

No it is not required. OU for instance [states](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/shehakol/)

> If you said she’hakol, mistakenly believing it was the correct
>   blessing for a higher level food, she’hakol does cover the food after
>   the fact and, b’di’avad (after the fact), you may eat the bread, wine, or other
>   higher-level food.

See also [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 56:4](http://draft.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.56.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi)

> Over any article of food, even over bread or wine, if, by mistake, you
>   recited the berachah Shehakol, you have fulfilled your obligation.

Comment: I remember learning that (at least according to some opinion) if one said *Shehakol* on a non-shehakol food, he can eat a little bit of it only, and then he should say the appropriate bracha before he eats the rest of the food. This is because shehakol only works for all foods as not to be a bracha levatala, but it does not become a bracha for eating the rest of it. [not so with *mezonos*, where he could eat all of it, since mezonos can *B'dieved* become the brachah for any food. Has anyone heard of this. Does anyone know the source? [Maybe *Igros Moshe*?]

Comment: Interesting. I can see the halachic logic but didn’t find a source. Looking forward to someone who did

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore See the Aruch Hashulchan quoted in my answer.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore it was Alex who mentioned the Aruch Hashulchan - see last quote in HIS answer